# User input length and members of array, two arrays

Tags: java, arrays, console

I need to get two 1-D arrays from the console for a comparison exercise. The first number input by the user is designated as the length of the arrays.

My code throws an error when I try to submit the numbers for the second array.
Thanks!

---

```
 public static boolean Equals( int [] list1, int[] list2)
    {
        if( list1.length != list2.length) return false;

        for (int i = 0; i < list1.length ; ++i)
            if  (list1[i] != list2[i] ) return false;

        return true;
    }    
    public static void main (String[]args)
    {
           Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
        //Prompt user for input

           int[] list1 = null, list2 = null;


            System.out.print("Enter list1: ");
            int x = input.nextInt();
            int []length = new int [x];
            for (int i = 0; i < list1.length ; i++) {
                x += list1[i];
            System.out.print("Enter list2: ");
            for (int j = 0; j < list2.length; j++) {
                x += list2[j];
            }


    if ( Equals (list1, list2))
        System.out.print("Two lists are strictly identical");
    else
        System.out.print("Two lists are not strictly identical");


}
```

Comment: You are missing a `}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You reference `list1` and `list2` without assigning them a value other than `null`, therefore you should get a `NullPointerException` at this line:

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i < list1.length ; i++) {
  ```
- Secondly, do not use custom `equals` methods (and watch Java [code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) on method naming - Java != C#). 
  Use `Arrays.equals` instead.